Intersections treat `number` and `boolean` differently
(TypeScript 5.4.5)
It's easy to understand that
interface A {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}
interface B {
  key: string;
  value: number;
}
type C = A & B // => { key: string; value: never; }
               // ^_^ string & string = string
               //     string & number = never

But when I change number to boolean...
interface A {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}
interface B {
  key: string;
  value: boolean;
}
type C = A & B // => never
               // ??? Why not { key: string; value: never; }


This behavior is described in this Github pull request (highlighting mine):

An intersection T1 & T2 & ... & Tn is equivalent to never when

two or more of the Tx types have properties with the same name, and
in at least one group of properties with the same name, some property has a literal type and no property has type never, and
the intersection of the types of the properties in such a group is never.


Your second example satisfies all those criteria, when you take into account that TypeScript actually considers boolean to be a literal union of true | false, as for example documented here:

Given that boolean is simply an alias for true | false, [...]

interface A {
  key: string;
  value: string;
}

interface B {
  key: string;
  value: boolean; // actually a boolean literal union (true | false)
}

type C = A & B; // never

Your first example does not resolve to never because the second condition is not met, i.e. none of the properties have a literal type. If we were to replace the string property with a string literal union, we witness the same behavior:
interface A {
  key: string;
  value: 'a' | 'b'; // replace string with a string literal union
}

interface B {
  key: string;
  value: number;
}

type C = A & B; // never


At one point in TS, it was decided that intersections that lead to impossible types will become never. PR
That is why both string & number and string & boolean become the type never.
Later it was decided, that intersections caused by discriminants would lead to the type collapsing to never. PR
type A = { kind: 'a', foo: string };
type B = { kind: 'b', foo: number };
type C = { kind: 'c', foo: number };

type AB = A & B;  // never
type BC = B & C;  // never

From the docs:

We have long speculated that intersections of object types with
discriminant properties of disjoint types should be eqivalent to never
(the empty type), since objects of such types are not possible to
construct. This PR finally implements that feature.

For the above rules to apply to a group Tx = T1 & T2 & T3...
We are looking for properties in some Ta & Tb,

with the same name
where at least some property has a literal type
and the intersection of the types becomes never

The difference in behavior is probably due to the fact that boolean is a type like true | false and number is not.
